# How can I change text (edit its contents or its class) once it is dynamically added to a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page where a user can make a list. They do this by inputting strings into a input box and then clicking a button to add that string as a list item. How can I change the class of these list items to put a line through the text when I click on one? or edit the contents of a list item?

I tried $('li').toggleClass("finishedItem") instead of 'p' too and no change I'm not sure what I am doing wrong any help is appreciated thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 addText();
 $('p').onclick = markComplete();
});
const $addBtn = $("#add");
const $newItemList = $('ul');
const $inputBox = $('input');

const addText = function () {
$addBtn.on("click", function () {
    addLI();
});
};
const addLI = function () {
if($inputBox.val()!=="")
{
    $newItemList.append("<li>" +"<p>"+ $inputBox.val() +"</p>" + " 
</li>");
}

};
const markComplete = function(){

$('p').toggleClass("finishedItem")

};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 addText();

});
const $addBtn = $("#add");
const $newItemList = $('ul');
const $inputBox = $('input');

const addText = function () {
$addBtn.on("click", function () {
    addLI();
});
};
const addLI = function () {
if($inputBox.val()!=="")
{
    $newItemList.append("<li>" +"<p onclick=\"$(this).attr('class', 'finishedItem');\">"+ $inputBox.val() +"</p>" + " 
</li>");
}

};
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It seems to be toggling all of the list items though is there a way that I can make it select only the individual list items? Also do I need to add p as a formal parameter for the markComplete function, and how would I do it?

Comment: Just use the code as is, p is already a parameter to the function

Comment: Works great thank you. Sorry to bother but would you mind explaining how that code you changed around works?

Comment: The inline onclick attribute dynamically created for the <li> element just uses jquery to set the class attribute, no need for a seperate function because its doing such a simple thing.